# Textarea without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi
I do want to create a textarea without scrollbar just like in facebook and twitter, and the creation of the textarea that changes its height when we click on it.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to use jQuery, there is a plugin called `autoResize`

Usage is simple:

```
$('textarea#comment').autoResize({
    // On resize:
    onResize : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
    },
    // After resize:
    animateCallback : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
    // Quite slow animation:
    animateDuration : 300,
    // More extra space:
    extraSpace : 40
});
```

Grab this plugin here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation over here http://www.dazecoop.com/22-10-2008/jquery-textarea-auto-grow-auto-height you just need to get the plugin ;)